# how to take text which is given link to other JSP page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I'm doing project as 'Question and Answer'. Registered user's can post their question and also can answer to open question. In one JSP page I have displayed list of questions asked by logged in user. I have displayed question list in table row. Have given link to each question. Now, I want to know how I retrieve and take question which is clicked to other JSP page. Please Suggest. Thank you in advance. Also give link to helpful resource so next time I will not have same kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- From the question list: You need to pass *GET parameters* together with your *URL to the Answers JSP*, which specify the question (e.g. least a question ID)
- On the server side, your *Answers JSP* has to evaluate the *question ID* and return the appropriate anwser in response

Comment: Here is a simple example of JSP page navigation: http://click.avoka.com/click-examples/jsp/navigation-b.htm?actionLink=forwardLink

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked and I'm through...